# If for every $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$ $d^k f ( x ) ( h )^k = 0 $, then $d^k f ( x ) = 0?$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a **infinitely differentiable real function**. Let ${d}^k f ( \mathbf{x} ) $ denotes the $k-$th diferential of the function $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$. Is it true that if ${d}^k f ( \mathbf{x} )(\mathbf{h})^{k}=0$ for all $\mathbf{h}\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ then ${d}^k f ( \mathbf{x} ) = \mathbf{0}$? For which values of $k$ this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true for every $k$. Your question is about whether we can recover a symmetric $k$-linear form from the corresponding form of of degree $k$. For $k=2$ this follows from the polarization identity
$$
B(h,k)=\frac{F(h+k)-F(h)-F(k)}{2}
$$
(here $F$ is the quadratic form and $B$ is the symmetric bilinear form). You can do the same for any $k$. Here is the corresponding identity
$$
M(h_1,h_2,\dots h_k)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^k(-1)^{k-r}\sum\limits_{i_1<i_2<\dots<i_r}[F(x_{i_1})+\dots F(x_{i_r})]
$$
Here, $F$ is the form of degree $k$ (in your case, $d^kf(x)(h,h,\dots h)$ and $M$ is the multilinear symmetric$k$-form. If $F\equiv 0$ then $M\equiv 0$, and $d^kf(x)\equiv 0$.

Comment: If one want explicity know which are the terms inside the $F$ function that he commented, then read the paper "A polarization identity for multilinear maps" that is avaible on the page: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1275.